# Prioritise a WHERE IN( ) when using a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table structure that links **Speakers** to **Presentations**, potentially multiple of the latter.

We give each Presentation a status of either **Live**, **Standby** or **Proposed**.

When I'm pulling out all the data (speakers/presentations), I'm grouping and ordering by Speaker so each only appears once in alphabetical order, however I need to prioritise which status comes out attached to that Speaker.

The order of priority is 1) Live, 2) Standby, 3) Proposed (therefore if a Speaker has one presentation that is Live and one that is on Standby, they will be pulled out with status Live.

I'm having trouble ordering these statuses however, but I believe I need to the `CASE` construct.

This is my *test query* as it stands, using only one Speaker (for simplicity) who has three presentations assigned, one of each status:

```
SELECT speaker_id, presentation_id, presentation_status 
FROM conf_presentation
INNER JOIN spk_pres USING(presentation_id) 
WHERE presentation_status IN('live','proposed','standby')
CASE
    WHEN presentation_status = 'live' THEN my_order = 1
    WHEN presentation_status = 'standby' THEN my_order = 2
    WHEN presentation_status = 'proposed' THEN my_order = 3
AND speaker_id = 16551
GROUP BY speaker_id
ORDER BY my_order
```

It currently has a syntax error somewhere, and even if that was fixed, I'm not sure if this is even how to do what I want to.

My expected result is as follows:

```
SPEAKER  PRESENTATION  STATUS
16551    20113         live
```

As without any `CASE`, the first Presentation in the table for this Speaker is returned:

```
SPEAKER  PRESENTATION  STATUS
16551    20227         proposed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of being able to control the order of the result picked WITHIN each group. Mysql doesnt have a way to directly do it. There are many ways to solve it... 
https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+within+group+order+by

Personally my favorite is using GROUP_CONCAT - as that allows ordering. And then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to extract just the first one. (and avoids complex sub-queries)

```
SELECT speaker_id, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(presentation_id ORDER BY FIELD(presentation_status, 'live', 'standby', 'proposed') ASC),',',1) AS presentation_id, 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(presentation_status ORDER BY FIELD(presentation_status, 'live', 'standby', 'proposed') ASC),',',1) AS presentation_status
FROM conf_presentation
INNER JOIN spk_pres USING(presentation_id) 
WHERE presentation_status IN('live','proposed','standby')
GROUP BY speaker_id
```

This uses `FIELD()` function like mentioned in the other answer. Which is better than the `CASE`.

... But even better would be to just make presentation_status an ENUM column. Then by putting the values in the right order, can ORDER BY the numberic context. eg use `ENUM('live','proposed','standby')` can then simply do

```
GROUP_CONCAT(presentation_id ORDER BY presentation_status+0 ASC)
```

This scales to all speakers. If want to choose the final order, can use ORDER BY as normal.

Answer (score 0):

The priority, if rarely changed, should really be stored in the database in a `presentation_status` table `(presentation_id, title, priority)` and referenced by the `spk_pres.presentation_id`.

Then you can `ORDER BY spk_pres.speaker_id, presentation_status.priority`.

I also like to include a table alias (normally table initials) with each of my columns in queries with a `JOIN` so that I can see where each of the columns are coming from, and also avoid conflicts, when reading the query in isolation. Here, I had to guess where `speaker_id` was coming from.

Comment: Doesn't a `GROUP BY` clause happen **before** an `ORDER BY` though?

Comment: It does, he should be using `MAX(presentation_status.priority)` instead.

Comment: @scragar, I fail to see how that would help.. you could include the priority in the GROUP BY in a similar manner to that suggested by Gordon Linoff and not SELECT it.. that would work.